# ComponentCallbacks2 trim level change

Tags: android, performance

Trying to implement ComponentCallbacks2 in my application. Few things which I didn't get clear answers from the documentation are

1. Can running trim levels go down while the app is running?. For example can it go from `TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL` to `RUNNING_LOW` or `RUNNING_MODERATE`.
2. Right now I'm getting lastTrimLevel only on onCreate. Should I get current `getMyMemoryState` on onResume expecting a lower `lastTrimLevel`?. The reason I'm asking is, Can there be a situation where if I pause the app after getting a `TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL`. And when I come back current level will be a lower `RUNNING_LOW` or `RUNNING_MODERATE`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility. Consider this scenario: There are 3 *running* processes viz. A, B and C. Process C is the 'greedy' one hogging the major chunk of resources. Suppose the system experiences a resource crunch and issues `onTrimMemory()` with level `TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL` to all 3 processes. While A and B promptly release resources reducing their memory footprint, the 'greedy' C holds ground without releasing any becoming the prime target to be killed by the system.

The system kills C and recovers its (huge *cache* of) resources. Now when an `onTrimMemory()` is issued, there is a fair chance that the passed-in level may be less severe than the `TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL` that was issued earlier. There are several variables at play here and one cannot predict what level will pop up when.